# Consulta SQL avançada com datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Eu estou com um problemas há dias. Tenho minha tabela e precisa contar quantas notas estão atrasadas, até ai tudo bem. Só que não sei fazer essa consulta. Preciso verificar se estão atrasadas, para ser atrasada ela tem que estar com uma diferença de 3 dias da data atual e dentro desses 3 dias eu preciso ignorar sábados e domingos , alguém sabem como posso fazer isso ? . Obrigado!

Estrutura da minha tabela!

```
codigo (int), NomeCLiente Varchar , Data_operacao (TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757919/count-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-mysql-only

Comment: Complemente sua pergunta com as pesquisas que já tentou fazer. Mesmo que elas não apresentem o resultado final (obviamente), elas irão mostrar o esforço e sua linha de raciocínio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM minha_tabela
WHERE (
    DATEDIF(CURDATE(),Data_operacao) <=5 AND 
    WEEKDAY(Data_operacao)=5
) OR (
    DATEDIF(CURDATE(),Data_operacao) <=4 AND
    WEEKDAY(Data_operacao)=6
) OR (
    DATEDIF(CURDATE(),Data_operacao) <=3  AND 
    WEEKDAY(Data_operacao)<5)
)
```

Lembrando que a função `WEEKDAY`  retorna:

- **0**: Segunda
- **1**: Terça
- ..
- **5**: Sábado
- **6**: Domingo